# Как настроить devise чтобы можно было отправлять "обычные" письма?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

Имеется настроенный devise, письма с подтверждением аккаунта, восстановлением пароля отправляются.
Есть "обычное" письмо, которое нормально отправлялось до установки devise`а:

```
class ServiceMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => 'notify@mysite.com'

  def notify_record(service_mail, record)
    @record = record
    mail(to: service_mail, subject: 'Новая запись')
  end
end

class RecordsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create

  def create
    # pp params
    r = Record.create(:name => params[:fio], :phone => params[:phone], :date => params[:date], :job_id => params[:job], :address_id => params[:address])


    ServiceMailer.notify_record(
      Service.joins(:addresses).where(:addresses => {:id => params[:address]}).first.email,
      r
      ).deliver_now

    render :json => {}, :status => 200
  end
end
```

Но сейчас получаю ошибку:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user
```

Что еще нужно настроить, чтобы заработало?

**Update**
Локально это все работает, проблема наблюдается только на сервере.

**Update 2**
Ответ найден:
При установке-настройке девайса была изменена учетная запись, с которой отправлялось письмо, а from осталось старым.

Comment: Похоже, что ваш SMTP-сервер не согласен отправлять от лица указанного адреса, т. к. по учётной записи он не ваш. Тот, что в `:from`, я полагаю.

Comment: @D-side , я попробовал заменить "default :from => 'notify@mysite.com'" на "default :from => 'support@mysite.com'", с таким from отправляет письма devise, но не это письмо. Проблема наблюдается только на сервере.

Comment: Я к тому, что скорее всего Devise и Rails вообще не при делах, выясняйте со своим почтовым сервисом, что не так. Потому что это он отказывается вас обслуживать.